# Flip last 3 bits of vector

Tags: matlab, binary

I have a uint16 vector which I need to flip the last 3 bits of every number.

I already have done this but I think there must be an easier solution to do this. Here is my code.

```
%Turn the vector to binary
V_bin = dec2bin(V,16);
for i=1:length(V)
  %Get the last 3 bits
  tmp = V_bin(14:end);
  %Convert the string to decimal
  tmpdec = bin2dec(tmp);
  %Do the flip
  tmpflip = bitcmp(uint8(tmpdec));
  %Flipped to binary
  tmpbin = dec2bin(tmpflip);
  %Replace the flipped bits in the original string
  V_bin(14:end) = tmpbin(6:end);
end
V = bin2dec(V_bin);
```

As you can see there are a lot of lines for a simple operation, I wonder if there is a more efficient method to do the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with matlab, but the [bitxor](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/bitxor.html) function looks appropriate for you, i.e.

```
V = bitxor(V, 7);
```

Comment: 7 is 111 in binary, i.e. the three least significant bits :)

Comment: Definitely this the kind of answer I was looking for, thanks :)

Comment: +1. If you want to pass a more readable bitmask argument, you can still use `bin2dec` or `hex2dec` to provide the arguments as binary or hex strings: `bitxor(V, bin2dec('0000 0111'))`. (And BTW, the names of "bin2dec", "dec2bin", and their relatives are lousy misleading; they really convert strings to (binary) numerics and vice versa.)